# Apache camel error: The method process is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: apache-camel, routes, processor

I have written a simple route, which would get any http request and save it in file:output.
Once saved a processor is created which would read all the requests.

Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.processor.*;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;


public class LoadBalancer {
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
          CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

            public void configure() {
                from("jetty://http://localhost:8080")
                .to("file:output");
                from("file://output").process(new processor()
                {
                    public void process(Exchange e)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Recieved exchange:" + e.getIn());
                    }
                }
                );
                //.loadBalance().roundRobin().to("http://172.28.39.138:8080","http://172.168.20.118:8080");
            }
        }); 

        context.start();

        Thread.sleep(100000);  
        context.stop();
    }
 }
```

Now when i compile it, i get the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method process(Processor) in the type ProcessorDefinition<RouteDefinition> is not applicable for the arguments (new processor(){})
    processor cannot be resolved to a type

On the line `from("file://output").process(new processor()`



I couldn't figure out what kind of error it it.
    Am I doing anything wrong in the code?
    Any help would be very much appreciated.

    Cheers!!
```

Comment: please tell me what IDE do you use to code, and regarding your error check out your processor spelling in new processor, P should be caps. Same goes for your import statement.

Comment: @Sikorski I use eclipse! I will check for the Caps and will keep you updated! thanks a ton for replying mate!

Comment: if you are using eclipse then make use of code completion, you won't get such problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inlined [Processors](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html) should be written like this...

```
from("file://output").process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Recieved exchange:" + e.getIn());
   }
});
```

Comment: This could isn't doing what it should do.
I want to log all the recieved exchanges on port 8080 and print it.
But though I send a soap request message from a web browser to my localhost, I don't recieve any request here.
Is what i am doing here correct? All i want is to have a route which could recieve the request and forward them to two backend servers.
Basically I need a proxy. Do i have any other options? And morover when i open my web rowser and type localhost:8080,
it opens a page with jetty error 404 reason: Not found. Please i need some serious help here.

Comment: maybe there is some issue with your jetty !

Comment: @Sikorski But what is it?? I am still struck here in this part. If not jetty what other options do i have? Do i have to separately install jetty, to use this code?? Thanx a ton for your support.

Comment: @Kishore i m confused by your last comment, on what server are you deploying your app.. also if you need to implement a Proxy using Camel, i think there is an example in camel's user guide (Google it)

Comment: @Sikorski Let me explain, what i am trying to do here, I have to build a load balancer that would listen to a port, which in my case is 8080 and distribute the load among other backend servers. Camel is not a server, so inorder to listen to a port I use camel-Jetty, but the problem here is my code doen't seem to work. As far as i know the routes are correct. The load balancing example in camel user guide uses mina to create backend servers, which in my case already exists. The example code doesn't seem to fit my scenario. Any help is appreciated.